# Openfigi REST API in node js

Tags: node.js, rest

I am trying to run the following Nodejs program to retrieve data from OpenFigi.
But, not getting any information whereas curl request returns the data.

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: 'https://api.openfigi.com/v1/mapping',
    data: '[{"idType":"ID_WERTPAPIER","idValue":"851399","exchCode":"US"}]',
    headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'text/json'
      }  }; 

function callback(error, response, body) {
   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
       var info = JSON.parse(body);
       console.log(info);
   } 
}

request(options, callback);
```

The following curl request returns the data

```
curl -v POST 'https://api.openfigi.com/v1/mapping'   \
   --header 'Content-Type: text/json'             \
   --data '[{"idType":"ID_WERTPAPIER","idValue":"851399","exchCode":"US"}]'
```

Result:

```
 [
  {
    "data": [
    {
    "figi": "BBG000BLNNH6",
    "securityType": "Common Stock",
    "marketSector": "Equity",
    "ticker": "IBM",
    "name": "INTL BUSINESS MACHINES CORP",
    "uniqueID": "EQ0010080100001000",
    }
   ]
  }
]
```

Could you please help to fix the nodejs program.

Thanks,
Saravana

Comment: What are you getting in `error` and `response.statusCode`?

Comment: Getting the following message.. request(options, callback);
Request {
  domain:
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] },
  _events:
   { error: [Function: bound ],
     complete: [Function: bound ],
     pipe: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 3,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  data: '[{"idType":"ID_WERTPAPIER","idValue":"851399","exchCode":"US"}]',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/json', host: 'api.openfigi.com' },
  callback: [Function],
  readable: true,
  writable: true,

Comment: it returns all the options and callback values, there is no error or errorcode and there is no data as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give `method type`

```
var options = {
    url: 'https://api.openfigi.com/v1/mapping',
    method:'POST',
    data: '[{"idType":"ID_WERTPAPIER","idValue":"851399","exchCode":"US"}]',
    headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'text/json'
      }  };
```

Comment: Thanks and I have to use 'body' instead of 'data'.